# If a Sum() value returns Null use 0, currently have it casting to a nullable double?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, nullable, sum

I have a LINQ statement which is working great... its part of  select here it is

```
 select new
 {
     Net = (System.Double?)
     ((from m0 in MOVTOS
     where m0.DocumentType == "NET" && m0.ClientCode == c.ClientCode
     group m0 by new { 0.ClientCode } into g
     select new
     {
         Expr1 = (System.Double)g.Sum(p => p.Amount)
     }).First().Expr1)
};
```

Now if you notice i am using `System.Double?` (nullable double) as a cast at the begging due to the fact that some values are returned as NULL on the SUM.

If i change it to System.Double it fails with error

> The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Double which is a non-nullable value type

So what i would like to do is return the value of the SUM but if it is NULL then enter a 0 in there.

Any help really appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
double? nullable = null;
double notNullable = nullable ?? 0;
```

In your case:

```
select new
{
    Net =
        (from m0 in MOVTOS
         where m0.DocumentType == "NET" && m0.ClientCode == c.ClientCode
         group m0 by new { 0.ClientCode } into g
         select g.Sum(p => p.Amount) ?? 0).First()
};
```

Comment: may be cause to exception `g.Sum(p => p.Amount) ?? 0).First()` instead use `g.Sum(p => p.Amount) ?? 0).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @Saeed, yes, but I didn't want to change the meaning of the OP's code

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `?? 0`

Change `.First().Expr1)` to `.First().Expr1) ?? 0`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can filter your collection `g` accordingly...

```
List<double?> dArr = new List<double?>( )
{
   1,
   3,
   null,
   5
};

double sum = dArr.Select( item =>
   {
       if( item.HasValue == false )
          return 0;
       else
          return item;
   } ).Sum( item => item.Value );
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Sum` you can use the `Aggregate` method with a seed of `0.0`. This does not require the use of nullable types, or explicit casting.

```
select new
{
    Net =
    ((from m0 in MOVTOS
    where m0.DocumentType == "NET" && m0.ClientCode == c.ClientCode
    group m0 by new { 0.ClientCode } into g
    select new
    {
        Expr1 = g.Aggregate(0.0, (a, p) => a + p.Amount)
    }).First().Expr1)
};
```